# I can't open my written python scripts

Tags: windows-10, python

I can't open my written python scripts from the folder I saved it. Basically, no action will occur (not even an error message). What should I do?

Comment: Does it let you execute them from the command line?

Comment: I actually did a wrong installation of Python, I've figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open the file by clicking on it?
Clicking on an executable file (i.e. a python script) on windows will execute the script and close on completion.
Try right-clicking on the file and selecting open with your favorite text editor.

Comment: I actually did a wrong installation of Python. I've figured it out. Thanks